# Befunge iterate multiple instructions

Tags: befunge

In Befunge-98, the `k` operator allows me to do this

```
1k12....@
```

The output of this will be `2110`. I am looking for a (short) way to iterate *multiple* instructions, e.g. I want the output to be `2121` – as if the `k` operator iterated `12` twice, not just the `1`.

Is there any way to get the `k` operator to do this? If not, what would be the shortest way to repeat a sequence `n` times – without using `p`, `g` and `_` or `|`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, because it would have to stop iterating after a certain point, and to do that it would need to use _ or |, or p to put, for example, a ^ to send the pointer out of the loop.

You could use w to exit from the loop, but I assume that since you don't want _ or |, that w is not allowed either.